# Ayuda con una consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Hola a todos estoy tratando de realizar un reporte de salida para una aplicación.

la salida es la siguiente, del producto que se esta dando salida, necesito obtener a quien se lo estoy dando, y el proveedor que me dio el producto.

este es la consulta.

```
SELECT      M.TipoMovimientoId,
                    MD.MovimientoId,
                    TM.Nombre AS Movimiento,
                    CAST(M.Fecha AS DATE) AS Fecha, 
                    M.PersonaId,
                    PER.Nombre AS Cliente,
                    MD.ProductoId,
                    P.Descripcion AS Material,
                    MD.PesoUnidadBruto AS Kilos,
                    MD.PesoUnidadTara AS Tara,
                    MD.PesoUnidadTotal AS TOTALK,
                    MD.PrecioUnidad AS Precio,
                    MD.SubTotalUnidad AS TOTAL,
                    X.Proveedor        
        FROM dbo.Movimiento AS M
        INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosDetalle AS MD ON M.Id = MD.MovimientoId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Producto AS P ON P.Id =  MD.ProductoId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Persona AS PER ON PER.Id = M.PersonaId
        INNER JOIN dbo.TipoMovimiento AS TM ON TM.Id = M.TipoMovimientoId
        RIGHT JOIN (

            SELECT MD.ProductoId, 
                   M.PersonaId, 
                   P.Nombre AS Proveedor  
            FROM dbo.Movimiento AS M    
            INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosDetalle AS MD ON M.Id = MD.MovimientoId
            INNER JOIN dbo.Persona AS P ON P.Id = M.PersonaId
            WHERE M.TipoMovimientoId = 'f09a747a-5b35-4ade-8577-6f721e5acb6f'

        ) AS X ON X.ProductoId = MD.ProductoId
        WHERE  M.TipoMovimientoId = 'c8566d25-3407-4869-a711-2cc895a167ce'  
        --AND CAST(M.Fecha AS DATE) = CAST(@FECHA AS DATE)
        ORDER BY M.Fecha DESC
```

el valor de la cadena `'f09a747a-5b35-4ade-8577-6f721e5acb6f'` es una entrada.

el de: `'c8566d25-3407-4869-a711-2cc895a167ce'` es una salida.

el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La salida de la fecha '2019-02-25' lo hice hoy, pero solo lo hice con 2 productos, litografia y aluminio cable. pero litografia se repite porque en la entrada que esta marcado en rojo entro con 2 proveedores. *mondragon y milan*.

y por eso me duplica el registro. entonces quisiera que solo me tomara un proveedor, pero no se como realizar la modificación.

este es el resultado que espero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtener el proveedor y el cliente de esa salida.

Gracias!.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con un top 1? igual no entiendo porque la subconsulta X busca tantos campos, si solo utilizas 1.

Comment: si agrego el top 1 en la subconsulta, solo me devuelve 1 en todo. utilizo en la subconsulta el proveedor. y productoid. fue una forma que se me ocurrio

Comment: EL productoid viene de otra tabla. Porque no haces la subconsulta esa directo en el select? si es solo para obtener un nombre. y ahi si, podes usar el top1. si no, como queres que sql decida que fila usar en cada caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez esto sirva. Me confunde un poco el hecho de que haya un RIGHT JOIN con los proveedores, lo cual no puede seguir esta opción. También falta el órden para seleccionar al proveedor que no se menciona aquí.

```
SELECT      M.TipoMovimientoId,
                    MD.MovimientoId,
                    TM.Nombre AS Movimiento,
                    CAST(M.Fecha AS DATE) AS Fecha, 
                    M.PersonaId,
                    PER.Nombre AS Cliente,
                    MD.ProductoId,
                    P.Descripcion AS Material,
                    MD.PesoUnidadBruto AS Kilos,
                    MD.PesoUnidadTara AS Tara,
                    MD.PesoUnidadTotal AS TOTALK,
                    MD.PrecioUnidad AS Precio,
                    MD.SubTotalUnidad AS TOTAL,
                    X.Proveedor        
        FROM dbo.Movimiento AS M
        INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosDetalle AS MD ON M.Id = MD.MovimientoId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Producto AS P ON P.Id =  MD.ProductoId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Persona AS PER ON PER.Id = M.PersonaId
        INNER JOIN dbo.TipoMovimiento AS TM ON TM.Id = M.TipoMovimientoId
        CROSS APPLY (

            SELECT TOP 1 
                   XP.Nombre AS Proveedor  
            FROM dbo.Movimiento AS XM    
            INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosDetalle AS XMD ON XM.Id = XMD.MovimientoId
            INNER JOIN dbo.Persona AS XP ON XP.Id = XM.PersonaId
            WHERE XM.TipoMovimientoId = 'f09a747a-5b35-4ade-8577-6f721e5acb6f'
            AND XMD.ProductoId = MD.ProductoId
            --ORDER BY ?
        ) AS X
        WHERE  M.TipoMovimientoId = 'c8566d25-3407-4869-a711-2cc895a167ce'  
        --AND CAST(M.Fecha AS DATE) = CAST(@FECHA AS DATE)
        ORDER BY M.Fecha DESC;
```

La otra opción es usando un Common Table Expression (CTE) para obtener los proveedores de los productos desde un inicio. Al final de cuentas, creo que a ambas opciones les falta que se les aplique algo de lógica más allá de lo expuesto para seleccionar al proveedor correcto.

```
WITH Entradas AS(

            SELECT MD.ProductoId
                   P.Nombre AS Proveedor,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY MD.ProductoId ORDER BY M.Fecha /*¿Esto es correcto?*/)  rn
            FROM dbo.Movimiento AS M    
            INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosDetalle AS MD ON M.Id = MD.MovimientoId
            INNER JOIN dbo.Persona AS P ON P.Id = M.PersonaId
            WHERE M.TipoMovimientoId = 'f09a747a-5b35-4ade-8577-6f721e5acb6f'
        )
SELECT      M.TipoMovimientoId,
                    MD.MovimientoId,
                    TM.Nombre AS Movimiento,
                    CAST(M.Fecha AS DATE) AS Fecha, 
                    M.PersonaId,
                    PER.Nombre AS Cliente,
                    MD.ProductoId,
                    P.Descripcion AS Material,
                    MD.PesoUnidadBruto AS Kilos,
                    MD.PesoUnidadTara AS Tara,
                    MD.PesoUnidadTotal AS TOTALK,
                    MD.PrecioUnidad AS Precio,
                    MD.SubTotalUnidad AS TOTAL,
                    e.Proveedor        
        FROM dbo.Movimiento AS M
        INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosDetalle AS MD ON M.Id = MD.MovimientoId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Producto AS P ON P.Id =  MD.ProductoId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Persona AS PER ON PER.Id = M.PersonaId
        INNER JOIN dbo.TipoMovimiento AS TM ON TM.Id = M.TipoMovimientoId
        RIGHT JOIN Entradas AS e ON MD.ProductoId = e.ProductoId
        WHERE  M.TipoMovimientoId = 'c8566d25-3407-4869-a711-2cc895a167ce'  
        AND e.rn = 1
        --AND CAST(M.Fecha AS DATE) = CAST(@FECHA AS DATE)
        ORDER BY M.Fecha DESC;
```

Comment: lo voy a revisar

Comment: Ya lo revisaste?